# How to position date picker in the center of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datepicker

I'm using the jQuery date picker on my project. Somehow I can't control its **position** to display in the center of the screen. I've tried.

```
div.ui-datepicker{
    font-size:20px;

    width: 500px !important;
    position:absolute !important;
    top:0 !important;
    right:0 !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;

    
}
```

[image]

## Live result

https://www.bunlongheng.com/baby/1?code=rithys4k

Click on the date on the top left, **datePicker** will trigger

Comment: Is this open source?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site. I am surprised you don't know that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with this css.

```
#ui-datepicker-div{
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 350px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 60px !important;
  right: unset !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/dR5RQ4j.png  Your result is center, center. Too center . I only want to mimic the red line shared, only center top part, but thanks for your suggestion, it's cool. Thank. 

Comment: You added `position: fixed !important;` what is that do? Can you explain a bit in the answer?

Comment: Please check this for this. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1):

I think I solve my own problem.

**Desktop**

```
div.ui-datepicker{
    font-size:20px;
    left: 12% !important; 
    top: 7% !important; 
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important; 
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

[image]

---

**Mobile**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    div.ui-datepicker{
        width: 90% !important; 
        left: 50% !important; 
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0) !important; 
    }
}
```

[image]